# How do I remove the nested array in cakephp

Tags: cakephp-2.3

How do I remove the nested array (int) 0 => array in the following array

```
    'Preference' => array(
              (int) 0 => array(
               'new_features' => '1'
           ),
             (int) 1 => array(
             'promos' => '1'
           ),
              (int) 2 => array(
              'daily_digest' => '0'
           )
        )
```

so that it looks like this

```
      'Preference' => array(
          'new_features' => '1',
          'promos' => '1',
          'daily_digest' => '0'
         )
       )
```

I am new to cakePHP any help is greatly appreciated. 
Using CakePHP 2.4.5

Comment: Please clarify your question....I think some more information should be added in this question for better understanding? for example why you want to do that?

Comment: Are you submitting a plain SQL query? Could you share here the code ?

Comment: Actually I was able to figure it out. The nested level was added because of how the form input fields were setup. For example: data[Preference][0][new_features] added the nested int() 0 array. Removing the [0] resolved my issue